# Intergrating a MATLAB model into Azure

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I am working on a Xamarin Forms app that is part of a wider project. That wider project includes the creation of an AI Model that is being trained with the data obtained from our app.

We need to start integrating the result of that model into our app. My first thoughts were wrapping a REST API (Azure App Service) around Azure Machine Learning Service. Having sat down with the data science team I've learn't that they have done all their work in MATLAB and have no python experience.

Is it feasible to have the MATLAB model running in Azure or should we move over to a Python implmentation that runs directly in Azure Machine Learning service?

Comment: Your question is very broad. But you can certainly run MATLAB code from Python

Answer (score 0):

That's a no here for MATLAB model, Here is the link to their reference architecture for cloud, https://www.mathworks.com/cloud/azure.html.

Comment: I'd skim-read those links before posting tis questio but i'd come away thinking that there was a supported solution for running MATLAB on a VM in Azure. WHen yo say "that's a no here" what do you mean?